# Trying to access array offset on value of type int { DefaultValueBinder.php line 82 }

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export-to-excel

I have an export to excel button which downloads excel file.
However when i click it shows me error as **Trying to access array offset on value of type int**

My code is this:

```
public static function dataTypeForValue($pValue = null)
    {
        // Match the value against a few data types
        if ($pValue === null) {
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NULL;
        } elseif ($pValue === '') {
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING;
        } elseif ($pValue instanceof PHPExcel_RichText) {
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_INLINE;
  } elseif ($pValue[0] === '=' && strlen($pValue) > 1) {   //error comes in this line
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA;
        } elseif (is_bool($pValue)) {
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_BOOL;
        } elseif (is_float($pValue) || is_int($pValue)) {
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC;
        } elseif (preg_match('/^[\+\-]?([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)([Ee][\-\+]?[0-2]?\d{1,3})?$/', $pValue)) {
            $tValue = ltrim($pValue, '+-');
            if (is_string($pValue) && $tValue[0] === '0' && strlen($tValue) > 1 && $tValue[1] !== '.') {
                return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING;
            } elseif ((strpos($pValue, '.') === false) && ($pValue > PHP_INT_MAX)) {
                return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING;
            }
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC;
        } elseif (is_string($pValue) && array_key_exists($pValue, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::getErrorCodes())) {
            return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_ERROR;
        }

        return PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING;
    }
}
```

what can be the solution for this..?

Comment: Which line here is line 82?

Answer (score 65):

In the PHPExcel file "DefaultValueBinder.php", replace this line 82:

```
} elseif ($pValue[0] === '=' && strlen($pValue) > 1) {
```

with the following:

```
} elseif (0 === strpos($pValue, '=') && strlen($pValue) > 1) {
```

Answer (score 4):

`(!is_int($pValue) && $pValue[0] === '=' && strlen($pValue) > 1)` should work. `$pValue[0]` will not work with integers so check if it is an int or not before continuing.

Comment: $pValue is a string

Comment: Well based on information you gave and on error code it looks like $pValue is an int. Where are you getting this value from?